# Neural network unable to predict

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Data (CSV): https://easyupload.io/firqeg

I'm trying to predict the last column of this data (binary) from the remaining columns. For this, I'm using neural networks (more to experiment with them at this point).

Some code follows, just to be transparent with what I'm doing but I also explain it to make it clear that this is not a coding question as the code works just fine. I'm using python.

I've scaled the cells using sklearn preprocessing:

```
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

I've split the data into a training set, validation set and testing set:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.3)
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)
```

I'm using a model of 2 hidden layers and 32 neurons in each:

```
model = Sequential([    
    Dense(20, activation='relu', input_shape=(22,)),    
    Dense(20, activation='relu'),    
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',              
              loss='binary_crossentropy',              
              metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,          
                 batch_size=32, epochs=100,          
                 validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

However the model never reaches any accuracy nor loss: https://prnt.sc/qzxmfe

Is the problem that there is missing data? Too many variables per observations? All insight appreciated!

EDIT: It's not too many variables as I reduced it to 3 variables that explain it well in a regression and get the same results.

Comment: What does it mean that it never reaches "any accuracy nor loss"? Do you mean that the accuracy/loss is very low, or that it is `NaN` or something else?

Comment: Explanatory picture: https://prnt.sc/qzxmfe

Comment: I should add I attempted with only 3 variables that do predict the dependent variable in a regression and get the same results so I'm wondering what's wrong with running a neural network on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your data contains missing values. For example, minimum of `np.array([np.nan, 10, -4.5])` is `nan`, and likewise the maximum. Any sum or difference of `nan` is also `nan`.

Dividing by `nan` yields `nan`, so all of  your data values are `nan` where the feature contains at least 1 `nan` value.

You need to somehow fix your missing values. The preferred method is [imputation](/questions/tagged/imputation). A bad option is deleting any values that are `nan`, or filling with some constant (like zero, the mean,  or the median).

Comment: Thank you, quick and concise with options on how to remedy.